# Does Interface Segregation Principle apply to data structures?

Tags: java, solid-principles, interface-segregation-principle

Lets imagine that we have a large data structure (lets call it `Configuration`) and various client classes (lets call them `Services`). Each service needs just one or two fields from `Configuration`.

If we inject the whole `Configuration` object to the various `Service`s, does this violate the ISP?
Does the fact that `Configuration` is technically a data structure and not a literal Java interface change the fundamental point behind ISP?

The practical dilemma I am facing is how configuration should become available to the various parts of my system. I have the option to use Spring's `@Value` annotation, through which each component gets precisely what it needs and nothing more. My second option is to make a `Configuration` instance available as a whole. In the second case, every component of the system would get the configuration of the whole system instead of getting only the few parts that it actually needs.

I am trying to understand whether the second option violates ISP.

Comment: Such things are guidelines, not iron-clad Rules That Must Be Obeyed.  Which choice makes your application easier to understand, more maintainable, etc?

Comment: As a first guess, I  think that the first one is easier. Testing for example. I think it requires more effort and more complexity to construct / mock the whole Configuration object than to simply pass a string or a boolean to the service. Still, my question now is whether ISP applies to large data structures, or whether it is strictly limited to interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly according to [Bob Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55073007/1371329), yes. His example of applying ISP to a `stack` certainly seems to imply that data structures are included.

On the other hand, this question is often asked of the Dependency Inversion Principle, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55012841/1371329), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59289400/1371329), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65772258/1371329). As I have answered in regard to the DIP, I don't think it makes sense to apply it to a data structure. Your mileage may vary when applying object-oriented principles to procedural-programming constructs.